# How do browsers deal with malformed HTML?

Tags: html, parsing, browser

I have a collection of documents that I'm attempting to parse.  Like HTML, they are fairly well structured and have a complex syntax/grammar.  Also like HTML, many of the documents do not fully adhere to the desired syntax.

My question is, what general strategies do browsers and HTML/XML parsing libraries use when parsing documents that don't strictly follow the right syntax?  They seem to deal with misplaced or missing tags well.  And I'm sure there are other situations, such as misspelled tags, incorrect attributes, etc. that must be dealt with and not simply ignored.

Comment: HTML5 specs explicitly define how to deal with malformed markup. (Previous standards didn't have this, so browsers have been dealing with it in their own way, usually trying to be as forgiving as possible.) As for misspelled tags/attributes, they are always ignored afaik (except maybe activating some quirks mode).

Comment: @Qtax can you provide a link to this part of the specs? I've found this http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html but it not mentions the word 'soup' and seems more narrow so I'm not sure. The FAQ does: http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_does_this_new_HTML_spec_legitimise_tag_soup.3F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Malformed or bad HTML is referred to as "tag soup".  Browsers have to deal with this and do so in different ways based on the browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc.), but here is a good article on tag soup and some general strategies:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it short:

- **in XML** any error in code terminates the parsing process - so called "*Draconian Error Handling*"
- **in XHTML** just as in any XML-based doc - error equals termination
- **in HTML** - the browser tries to render as much, as it can

Answer (score -1):

BEHOLD:

[The HTML5 Parsing Algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html)

Comment: Alas, I behold only a 404 page.

Comment: @MarkAmery I think [Parsing HTML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#parsing-html-documents) is what he/she meant.